# Solving Linear ODE using matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]

What I don't understand here is where or how the operator for this solution is formed. Shouldn't the values of the operator be A=(1,0,0,1)? (in the form a11, a12, a13, a14 respectively).

Any help on this topic is hugely appreciated. Thank You

Comment: it means that $\begin{pmatrix}\dot x\\\dot y\end{pmatrix}=A\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}y\\x\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

If we set $X'=\begin{pmatrix}
  x'(t)\\
  y'(t)
\end{pmatrix}$ and consider the following system $$ \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            x'(t)=\color{blue}{0}\cdot x(t)+\color{red}{1}\cdot y(t)\\
            y'(t)=\color{red}{1}\cdot x(t)+\color{blue}{0}\cdot y(t)
        \end{array}
    \right.$$ as $$X'(t)=A~X(t)$$ in which $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
  \color{blue}{0} & \color{red}{1} \\
  \color{red}{1} & \color{blue}{0}\\
  \end{pmatrix}$$ then you can find why that matrix selected.

Comment: Nice use of color! +1

Comment: @BabakS.: Nice answer =1